# PHP Com Excel Apply Filters

Tags: php, excel, web, ms-office

I am opening excel with com and it is working fine however I am having trouble apply two filters at the same time to same column. Here is the code:

```
$excel = new COM("excel.application") or die("Unable to instanciate excel");
$excel->Visible = 1;
$excel->DisplayAlerts = 1;

$wb = $excel->Workbooks->Open($dataFile);
$sheet = $wb->Worksheets(1);

// apply filters
$sheet->range("AS1")->AutoFilter(45, '<>'); // works with single filter
```

However when I want to apply two filters at the same time to same column, it doesnt work:

```
$sheet->range("AS1")->AutoFilter(45, '<> AND > 0'); // DOES NOT WORK
```

My guess is that instead of using `AND` as literal string in above statement, I should use actual excel constant `Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlAnd` but I am unable to get it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: **DISCLAIMER** - _I do not know the tools you are using nor will I pretend to._ With that said, it looks like it may be possible to switch the logic? E.g. `$sheet->range("AS1")->AutoFilter(45, '> 0 AND <>');`? I am assuming this as it looks like it goes in between something?

Comment: @SamSwift웃 Thanks I am using PHP. Nope that didn't work either :(

Answer (score 0):

Okay figured it out, I had to pass extra parameters:

```
define('xlAnd', 1);

$sheet->range("AS1")->AutoFilter(45, '<>', xlAnd, '> 0');
```